# Returning an iterator to an element in STL Container

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

how would you check if the iterator that was returned by the function points to something in container class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators are passed around as [begin,end) pairs, with the end value signifying "not found" or other forms of the empty sequence.  Return that from your function, or return a `pair<bool,iterator>` (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Make sure you return a valid iterator.

Well I suppose you could by iterating through the container and checking to see if the iterators are equal.  But that would be horrid.